# Javascript created elements not posting on submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Ive posted a few times but I'm still not coming right with this problem so below is the all the code, the problem is that the dynamically created elements are not appearing in _POST after submission. but I do see them in the modified source in firefox.

The Javascript inserts elements in between the following div,

```
                        <div id="p_scents">
                        </div>
```

but as mentioned do not show in in _POST

Below is the full source code so the problem can be replicated.

```
    <html >
    <head>

    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">




    $(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="url' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').on('click', function() {
    if( i > 1  ) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
    });
    });

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($){

    var jcrop_api;

    $('#target').Jcrop({
    onChange:   showCoords,
    onSelect:   showCoords,
    onRelease:  clearCoords
    },function(){
    jcrop_api = this;
    });

    $('#coords').on('change','input',function(e){
    var x1 = $('#x1').val(),
    x2 = $('#x2').val(),
    y1 = $('#y1').val(),
     y2 = $('#y2').val();
    jcrop_api.setSelect([x1,y1,x2,y2]);
    });

     });

    function showCoords(c)
    {
         $('#x1').val(c.x);
     $('#y1').val(c.y);
     $('#x2').val(c.x2);
             $('#y2').val(c.y2);
         $('#w').val(c.w);
     $('#h').val(c.h);
    };

     function clearCoords()
      {
     $('#coords input').val('');
      };


    </script> 


        </head>
        <body>
                <table border=1 cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0"  width=80%>
        <form action="/index.php/create" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">                      <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                       Select image
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                          <input type="file" name="image"/>
                                                    </td>
                                            </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan=2 align=center>

                        <a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                                         <tr><td>
                                                    Give your banner a unique name</td>
                                            <td>
                                              <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" autofocus />                                                </td></tr>
                                          <tr><td>Specify email address or domain to brand</td>
                                              <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="domainName" value="" id="domain" />                                                  </td></tr>
                                          <tr><td>Status</td>
                                            <td>
                                             <select name="status">
                    <option value="enabled">Enabled</option>
                    <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
                    </select>                                                </td></tr>
                                          <tr><td>Give you banner a default URL</td>
                                             <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="url" value="" id="url" />                                                </td></tr>
                    <tr><td valign=top>Alternate Urls
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="p_scents">
                        </div>
                    <input type=submit>
                    </form>                     </td>
                    </tr>


        </table>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid – you can’t have a `form` as child element of `table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple nesting errors in your HTML. Your `<form>` tag is put immediately inside the `<table>` - that is **incorrect**! Also the enclosing tag of the `form` is put inside the last `<td>`. Your markup should look like this:

```
<form ...>
    <table ...>
        <tr ...>
            <td ...>
                ...
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks,. if this sorts my problem out.. i'll kiss your toes.

Comment: I'll hold you to your word ;)